# how to make extras lines to hide with "..." with only two line

Tags: html, css

How to make extras lines hide with "..." ellipsis?

my code is

```
<p className="detail">
random string The Glenwood Plan boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings
</p>
```

output in html page

---

random string The Glenwood Plan boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin
Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior
Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms
-2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings
boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with
Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams
Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings

---

but I want to show output in just two lines and other words I don't want to show

So new output i want to show is

---

random string The Glenwood Plan boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin
Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior...

---

and at last I want to show ...

so any code for this ?

Comment: [Many more answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+ellipsis+after+lines+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

Use line clamp: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

sample code:

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `line-clamp` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp):

```css
.detail {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="detail">
  random string The Glenwood Plan boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms
  -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings boasts 3 bedrooms -2 baths. Interior Paint is Sherwin Williams
  Agreeable Gray with Extra White Ceilings
</p>
```